# Does cron automatically adjust to a timezone change?

Tags: cron, schedule, timezone

I added a `cron` job with `crontab -e`. Then, I changed the timezone.

However, it seems as if the `cron` job is still firing in the old timezone.

Do I need to restart it `cron`? (e.g. `service cron reload`)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to restart `cron`. However, `service cron reload` only reloads configuration files, and doesn't apply the new timezone. Use this (similar) command:

```
service cron restart
```